# Reduce Image Sizes on wordpress woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

I have just created a wordpress woocommerce store. But the images on the store are just 2 big. A row can only fit 3 Product images bcuz the images are too big.

Website url: http://bookfare.naijatalksense.com/

Please give me some fix to make it small and also something to make a row fit almost 5 product images.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Override theme default specification for product # per row
function loop_columns() {
 return 5; // 5 products per row
 }
 add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
```

You can also refer to this: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/

CSS For the products:

```
  .woocommerce ul.products li.product a img 
  {
   height: 400px !important;
  }
```